# Get request URL from the header in the Network Tab, and store into string

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I am using Selenium to test generating a report based on selected parameters. When my test clicks the 'Get Report' button, a report is generated, but as an image, so I can't check that the parameters that I've previously selected, are the ones present via web elements, as would usually do in Selenium. What I can do is get the API response body, and assert against that, but I have to hard-code the request URL, because I can't find a way of dynamically fetching it from the Network tab post clicking the button. The request URL has a query string including date and time, so I can't just have it hard-coded as a string, I need to be able to fetch it dynamically, store it into a string, that I can then pass into my function that then gets the API response.

Is this possible to do, and if so, what is the correct method/way of doing it in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to update this, just in case its a question that somebody else needs an answer to, but I managed to find the solution:
What the code is doing is collecting all of the event data happening at the point in my test. The static void 'Session_DevToolsEventReceived' then loops until it finds the "documentURL" which is the event name that I'm looking for.

```
        IDevTools devTools = (IDevTools)driver;
        DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
        var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
        await domains.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());
        domains.Network.Session.DevToolsEventReceived += Session_DevToolsEventReceived;
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("getResultsBtn")).Click();

        static void Session_DevToolsEventReceived(object? sender, DevToolsEventReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            _url ??= e.EventData["documentURL"]?.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**